# How to deal with a change in library's API to avoid breaking user code in Python

Tags: python, software-design

I wrote some Python scripts and Jupyter notebooks which are shared in our laboratory.

Every once in a while a new colleague tries one of my scripts/notebooks and complains that it doesn't work with a very cryptic error message. It turns out, the colleague has a new version of a library (matplotlib for instance) installed, which has an API change that breaks down my script/notebook.

My solution is to have an 'archived' version of Anaconda, with which I know that my scripts/notebooks works and tell the colleague to use this version of Anaconda. Problems are:

1. Not very user-friendly and wastes time (reinstall Anaconda, reinstall some other libraries plus debugging time).
2. If the colleague needs to update the library due to some bug fix or whatnot, either directly or indirectly as a dependency on other library, then it will break down again.

What would be the more user-friendly solution??

Edit: Putting my scripts/notebooks on a server is not an option since our IT department is very restrictive about setting servers. I'm think more along the lines of 'bundling' or 'compiling' my scripts with the required libraries

Comment: Have you tried [virtual envs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [docker container](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerized-python-development-part-1/) ?

Comment: Thanks @Junkrat for the prompt answer: do docker container require a server? Our IT department is very restrictive about setting up servers

Comment: Thanks @Carlo, I didn't know about setting up a conda environment manually, I will give it a try

Comment: In order to avoid any sort of troubles from the IT dept, your best bet is to use virtual envs.